# Efficiently change individual elements in matrix/array in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am running a simulation in R, which I am trying to make more efficient.

A little bit of background: this is an abstract simulation to test the effects of mutation on a population. The population has N individuals and each individuals has a genotype of M letters, each letter can be one of the twenty amino acids (I denote as 0:19).

One of the most (computationally) expensive tasks involves taking a matrix "mat" with M rows and N columns, which initially starts as a matrix of all zeroes,

```
mat <- matrix(rep(0,M*N),nrow=M)
```

And then changing (mutating) at least one letter in the genotype of each individual. The reason I say at least is, I would ideally like to set a mutation rate (mutrate) that, if I set to 2 in my overall simulation function, it will cause 2 mutations in the matrix per individual.

I found two rather computationally expensive ways to do so. As you can see below, only the second method incorporates the mutation rate parameter mutrate (I could not easily of think how to incorporate it into the first).

```
   #method 1
   for(i in 1:N){
   position <- floor(runif(N, min=0, max=M))
   letter <- floor(runif(N, min=0, max=19))
   mat[position[i],i] = letter[i]}
   #method 2, somewhat faster and incorporates mutation rate
mat <- apply(mat,2,function(x) (x+sample(c(rep(0,M-mutrate),sample(0:19,size=mutrate))%%20))))
```

The second method incorporates a modulus because genotype values have to be between 0 and 19 as I mentioned.

A few additional notes for clarity:

- I don't strictly need every individual to get exactly the same mutation amount. But that being said, the distribution should be narrow enough such that, if mutrate = 2, most individuals get two mutations, some one, some maybe three. I don't want however one individual getting a huge amount of mutations and many individuals getting no mutations Notably, some mutations will change the letter into the same letter, and so for a large population size N, the expected average number of mutations is slightly less than the assigned mutrate.
- I believe the answer has something to do with the ability to use the square-bracket subsetting method to obtain one random element from every column of the matrix mat. However, I could not find any information about how to use the syntax to isolate one random element from every column of a matrix. mat[sample(1:M),sample(1:N)] obviously gives you the whole matrix... perhaps I am missing something stupidly clear here.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question first; you can access a single cell in a matrix with `mat[row,column]`, or multiple scattered cells by their sequential cell id. Cell `1,1` is the first cell, followed by `2,1`, `3,1`, etc:

```
mat <- matrix(rep(0, 5*5), nrow=5)
mat[c(1,3,5,7,9)] = c(1,2,3,4,5)

mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    4    0    0    0
[3,]    2    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    5    0    0    0
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0
```

Accessing / overwriting the individual cells is fast too however. The fastest way that I could think of to perform your task, is to first create vectors for the values we want. A vector of all column indices (every column as many times as `mutrate`), a vector of row indices (randomly), and a vector of new values for these column/row combinations (randomly).

```
cols = rep(seq_len(N), mutrate)
rows = sample(M, N*mutrate, replace = T)
values = sample(genotypes, N*mutrate, replace = T) - 1 # -1 offset since genotypes are 0-indexed

for(i in seq_len(N*mutrate)) {
  mat[rows[i],cols[i]] = values[i]
}
```

Instead of that for-loop to update the matrix, we can also calculate the cell-IDs so we can update all matrix cells in one go:

```
cols = rep(seq_len(N), mutrate)
rows = sample(M, N*mutrate, replace = T)
cellid = rows + (cols-1)*M
  
values = sample(genotypes, N*mutrate, replace = T) - 1 # -1 offset since genotypes are 0-indexed
  
mat[cellid] = values
```

Trying with a 6000x10000 matrix to benchmark the multiple methods, shows how fast each method is:

```html
N = 6000  # individuals
M = 10000 # genotype length

genotypes = 20
mutrate = 2

method1 <- function() {
  
  mat <- matrix(rep(0,M*N),nrow=M)
  
  for(i in 1:(N*mutrate)){
    position <- sample(M, 1)
    letter <- sample(genotypes, 1) - 1
    mat[position,i%%N] = letter
  }
  
  return(mat)
  
}

method2 <- function() {
  
  mat <- matrix(rep(0,M*N),nrow=M)
  mat <- apply(mat,2,function(x) (x+sample(c(rep(0,M-mutrate),sample(0:19,size=mutrate))%%20)))
  
}

method3 <- function() {
  
  mat <- matrix(rep(0,M*N),nrow=M)
  
  cols = rep(seq_len(N), mutrate)
  rows = sample(M, N*mutrate, replace = T)
  values = sample(genotypes, N*mutrate, replace = T) - 1 # -1 offset since genotypes are 0-indexed
  
  for(i in seq_len(N*mutrate)) {
    mat[rows[i],cols[i]] = values[i]
  }
  
  return(mat)
  
}

method4 <- function() {
  
  mat <- matrix(rep(0,M*N),nrow=M)
  
  cols = rep(seq_len(N), mutrate)
  rows = sample(M, N*mutrate, replace = T)
  cellid = rows + (cols-1)*M
  
  values = sample(genotypes, N*mutrate, replace = T) - 1 # -1 offset since genotypes are 0-indexed
  
  mat[cellid] = values
  
  return(mat)
  
}

benchmark <- function(func, times=10) {
  begin <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
  for(i in seq_len(times))
    retval <- eval(parse(text=func))
  end <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
  cat(func, 'took', (end-begin)/times, 'seconds\n')
  return(retval)
}

ret1 <- benchmark('method1()')
ret2 <- benchmark('method2()')
ret3 <- benchmark('method3()')
ret4 <- benchmark('method4()')
```

*I've modified your first method to speed it up and perform mutrate.*

```
method1() took 0.8936087 seconds
method2() took 8.767686 seconds
method3() took 0.7008878 seconds
method4() took 0.6548331 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks! My last question was more exactly about multiple single cells. I guess I was wondering if all of the cells can be replaced in one assignment rather than a for loop through the entire N*mutrate sequence length. Also, your answer made me realize that leaving "position <-... letter <- ..." out of the loop would make method 1 much faster than it is (because the way I wrote it it's actually creating a new vector every time). Simple fix, thanks for pointing that out.  I may just leave this question open for a few more days but your fix definitely drastically improved my algorithm.

Comment: @DanKehila I've added another method to the answer, showing how we can use cell indices to update multiple non-contiguous cells all at once. I've also made a small edit to your first method, fetching a single sample each time. Indeed generating a single large vector with all new values outside of the loop is a solution too, it might perform a little faster.

Comment: Wow, you did it. Very informative. Thanks for sharing your expertise